# Imported function seems to run differently than original implementation

Tags: haskell, import

I have a function in MancalaBoard.hs that looks like this:

```
allowedMoves :: MancalaBoard -> Player -> [Int]
allowedMoves board p
    | (p == PlayerA && getCurPlayer board == p) = findIndices (>0) (init(take (length (playerSide board PlayerA)+1) (getBoardData board)))
    | (p == PlayerB && getCurPlayer board == p) = map (+(length (playerSide board PlayerA))) (findIndices (>0) (init(drop (length (playerSide board PlayerA)) (getBoardData board))))
    | otherwise = []
```

For reference, MancalaBoard is this:

```
data MancalaBoard = MancalaBoardImpl [Int] Player
```

When I run MancalaBoard.hs, I can do this:

```
*MancalaBoard> let board = [5,0,2,7,0,1,5,6,1,7,7,5,0,2] :: [Int]
*MancalaBoard> let mboard = MancalaBoardImpl board PlayerB
*MancalaBoard> move mboard 7
Player A: [5,0,2,7,0,1,5]
Player B: [0,2,8,8,6,1,3]
Current turn: PlayerB
```

But I have another file called TwoPlayerMancala.hs that imports MancalaBoard. When I try to do the same move in this file, I get an error:

```
Player A: [5,0,2,7,0,1,5]
Player B: [6,1,7,7,5,0,2]
Current turn: PlayerB
Player B, please make your move
7
*** Exception: Not an allowed move
```

Any idea why this might happen? Here's a full copy of both files in case it helps:

```
module MancalaBoard (MancalaBoard, Player, initial, getCurPlayer,
            getBoardData, numCaptured, move, allowedMoves, isAllowedMove,
            gameOver, winners) where

import Data.List as List -- for List.elemIndex
import Data.Maybe as Maybe -- for List.elemIndex

{-
 - The stones on a Mancala board are simply recorded as a list of Ints.  The
 -  Ints come in the following order:
 - 1. The boardSize pits belonging to PlayerA
 - 2. The store belonging to PlayerA
 - 3. The boardSize pits belonging to PlayerB
 - 4. The store belonging to PlayerB
 -}

data MancalaBoard = MancalaBoardImpl [Int] Player

data Player = PlayerA | PlayerB deriving (Eq, Show)

---- Functions/constants for Player ----

allPlayers = [PlayerA, PlayerB]
numPlayers = length allPlayers


playerNum :: Player -> Int
playerNum p = fromJust $ List.elemIndex p allPlayers


playerWithNum :: Int -> Player
playerWithNum i = allPlayers !! i


nextPlayer :: Player -> Player
{- Find the player whose turn is next -}
nextPlayer p = playerWithNum $ ((playerNum p) + 1) `mod` numPlayers


---- Functions/constants for MancalaBoard ----

{- number of pits on each side -}
boardSize = 6
{- number of stones in each pit -}
startStones = 4

{- the initial mancala board -}
initial :: MancalaBoard
initial = MancalaBoardImpl (concat $ take numPlayers (repeat boardSide)) PlayerA
                        -- One side of board                pit at end
    where boardSide = take boardSize (repeat startStones) ++ [0]


{- return the index of the first pit belonging to a player -}
indexForFirstPit :: Player -> Int
indexForFirstPit p = (playerNum p) * (boardSize + 1)


{- return the index of the store for that player -}
indexForPlayerStore :: Player -> Int
indexForPlayerStore p = boardSize + (indexForFirstPit p)


{- return the indices for the pits (without the store) for a player -}
indicesForPlayerSide :: Player -> [Int]
indicesForPlayerSide p = [firstPit .. lastPit] where
    firstPit = indexForFirstPit p
    lastPit = firstPit + boardSize - 1


---- Retrieve information about Mancala Board
{- return the player who has the current turn -}
getCurPlayer :: MancalaBoard -> Player
getCurPlayer (MancalaBoardImpl xs player) = player


{- return the list of all pits in the board -}
getBoardData :: MancalaBoard -> [Int]
getBoardData (MancalaBoardImpl xs player) = xs

{- return the side of the board for a specified player, including the store at
 - the end -}
playerSide :: MancalaBoard -> Player -> [Int]
playerSide (MancalaBoardImpl xs player) p
    | (p == PlayerA) = take (length xs `div` 2) xs
    | (p == PlayerB) = drop (length xs `div` 2) xs

{- return the number of captured pieces in specified player's store -}
numCaptured :: MancalaBoard -> Player -> Int
numCaptured board p = last $ playerSide board p

{- allowedMoves returns a list of valid moves for the current player:
 - ie. the indices of pits which belong to that player, and which contain one
 - or more pieces -}
allowedMoves :: MancalaBoard -> Player -> [Int]
allowedMoves board p
    | (p == PlayerA && getCurPlayer board == p) = findIndices (>0) (init(take (length (playerSide board PlayerA)+1) (getBoardData board)))
    | (p == PlayerB && getCurPlayer board == p) = map (+(length (playerSide board PlayerA))) (findIndices (>0) (init(drop (length (playerSide board PlayerA)) (getBoardData board))))
    | otherwise = []

{- check that a move is valid for the current player -}
isAllowedMove :: MancalaBoard -> Int -> Bool
isAllowedMove board q = q `elem` allowedMoves board (getCurPlayer board)

{- We number the pits from 0 to 13 (2 players, 6 pits each and 1 store each)
 - This function takes a board and applies the move where the player selects
 - the numbered pit, giving back an updated board after the move -}
move :: MancalaBoard -> Int -> MancalaBoard
move (MancalaBoardImpl xs PlayerA) n
    | ((isAllowedMove (MancalaBoardImpl xs PlayerA) n) == True) = (MancalaBoardImpl intmap (choose PlayerA))
    | otherwise = error "Not an allowed move" where
        q = xs !! n
        plusoned = map (+1) (take q (drop (n+1) xs))
        intmap = (take n xs) ++ [0] ++ plusoned ++ drop (n+1+q) xs
        choose plyr 
            | (n + q == 6) = PlayerA
            | otherwise = PlayerB
move (MancalaBoardImpl xs PlayerB) n
    | ((isAllowedMove (MancalaBoardImpl xs PlayerB) n) == True) = (MancalaBoardImpl reswapsides (choose PlayerB))
    | otherwise = error "Not an allowed move" where
        swapsides = drop (length xs `div` 2) xs ++ take (length xs `div` 2) xs
        performmove = getBoardData $ move (MancalaBoardImpl swapsides PlayerA) (n - (length xs `div` 2))
        reswapsides = drop (length xs `div` 2) performmove ++ take (length xs `div` 2) performmove
        choose plyr
            | (n + (xs !! n) == 13) = PlayerB
            | otherwise = PlayerA

{- gameOver checks to see if the game is over (i.e. if one player's side of the
 - board is all empty -}
gameOver :: MancalaBoard -> Bool
gameOver board = (all (==0) (init (playerSide board PlayerA))) || (all (==0) (init (playerSide board PlayerB)))

{- winner returns a list of players who have the top score: there will only be 
 - one in the list if there is a clear winner, and none if it is a draw -}
winners :: MancalaBoard -> [Player]
winners board = filter g allPlayers 
    where g plyr 
            | (sum(playerSide board plyr) == maximum (mapsum board)) = True
            | otherwise = False 
          mapsum board = map f allPlayers
          f plyr = sum (playerSide board plyr)    

---- show
instance Show MancalaBoard where
    show (MancalaBoardImpl boardData player) =
           -- (show boardData) ++ " " ++ (show player)
        "Player A: " ++ (show (take ((length boardData) `div` 2) boardData)) ++ "\n" ++
        "Player B: " ++ (show (drop ((length boardData) `div` 2) boardData)) ++ "\n" ++
        "Current turn: " ++ (show player)

---- tests

testboard1 = MancalaBoardImpl [4,4,4,4,4,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0] PlayerA
testboard2 = MancalaBoardImpl [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,5,5,5,0,0,7] PlayerB
testboard3 = MancalaBoardImpl [1,1,1,1,1,1,18,2,2,2,2,2,2,12] PlayerA
testboard4 = MancalaBoardImpl [0,1,0,2,0,3,6,5,0,10,0,15,0,21] PlayerB

testGetCurPlayer = (getCurPlayer testboard1 == PlayerA)

testGetBoardData = (getBoardData testboard2 == [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,5,5,5,0,0,7])

testPlayerSide = (playerSide testboard3 PlayerA == [1,1,1,1,1,1,18])

testNumCaptured = (numCaptured testboard4 PlayerB == 21)

testAllowedMoves = (allowedMoves testboard1 PlayerA == [0,1,2,3,4,5])

testIsAllowedMove = (isAllowedMove testboard2 0 == False)

testMove = (getCurPlayer(move testboard4 9) == PlayerA) && (getBoardData(move testboard4 9) == [1,2,1,3,1,4,6,5,0,0,1,16,1,22])

testGameOver = (gameOver testboard3 == False)

testWinners = (winners testboard1 == [PlayerA,PlayerB])
```

and

```
-- TwoPlayerMancala.hs
import MancalaBoard

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Welcome! This program allows two people to play Mancala with each other."
    putStrLn "For Player A, their pits are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. 6 is their store."
    putStrLn "For Player B, their pits are numbered 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, and 12. 13 is their store."
    putStrLn "In other words, this program represents a board that looks like this:"
    putStrLn "[  ] [ 0] [ 1] [ 2] [ 3] [ 4] [ 5] [ 6]"    
    putStrLn "[13] [12] [11] [10] [ 9] [ 8] [ 7] [  ]"
    putStrLn "Balls travel counterclockwise on this board."
    putStrLn "To quit, enter \"quit\" at any point"
    putStrLn "The game begins now."
    playGame

playGame :: IO ()
playGame = do
    putStrLn $ show initial 
    n <- getLine
    let num = read n :: Int
    makeMove initial num

makeMove board n = do
    let board1 = move board n
    putStrLn $ show board1
    if (gameOver board1) 
    then endGame board1
    else return ()
    if (show (getCurPlayer board1) == "PlayerA") then putStrLn "Player A, please make your move"
    else putStrLn "Player B, please make your move"
    m <- getLine
    if (m == "quit") 
    then endGame board1
    else return ()
    let mum = read m :: Int
    makeMove board1 mum

endGame :: MancalaBoard -> IO ()
endGame board = do
    putStrLn "The game is over! Here is the final board: "
    putStrLn $ show board
    putStrLn "The winner is: "
    putStrLn $ show (winners board)
    return ()

    {-if ((winners board) == [PlayerA]) 
    then let winner = "Player A" else 
    if ((winners board) == [PlayerB]) 
    then let winner = "Player B" else 
    let winner = ""
    putStrLn "The game is over! Here is the final board:"
    putStrLn $ show board
    if (winner == ("Player A" || "Player B")) 
    then putStrLn "The winner is " ++ winner
    else putStrLn "The game was a tie!"-}
```

*** edit ***
Here's the full input and output that leads to the error:

```
*Main> main
Welcome! This program allows two people to play Mancala with each other.
For Player A, their pits are numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. 6 is their store.
For Player B, their pits are numbered 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, and 12. 13 is their store.
In other words, this program represents a board that looks like this:
[  ] [ 0] [ 1] [ 2] [ 3] [ 4] [ 5] [ 6]
[13] [12] [11] [10] [ 9] [ 8] [ 7] [  ]
Balls travel counterclockwise on this board.
To quit, enter "quit" at any point
The game begins now.
Player A: [4,4,4,4,4,4,0]
Player B: [4,4,4,4,4,4,0]
Current turn: PlayerA
2
Player A: [4,4,0,5,5,5,1]
Player B: [4,4,4,4,4,4,0]
Current turn: PlayerA
Player A, please make your move
5
Player A: [4,4,0,5,5,0,2]
Player B: [5,5,5,5,4,4,0]
Current turn: PlayerB
Player B, please make your move
8
Player A: [4,4,0,5,5,0,2]
Player B: [5,0,6,6,5,5,1]
Current turn: PlayerB
Player B, please make your move
12
Player A: [5,5,1,6,5,0,2]
Player B: [5,0,6,6,5,0,2]
Current turn: PlayerA
Player A, please make your move
1
Player A: [5,0,2,7,6,1,3]
Player B: [5,0,6,6,5,0,2]
Current turn: PlayerA
Player A, please make your move
5
Player A: [5,0,2,7,6,0,4]
Player B: [5,0,6,6,5,0,2]
Current turn: PlayerA
Player A, please make your move
4
Player A: [5,0,2,7,0,1,5]
Player B: [6,1,7,7,5,0,2]
Current turn: PlayerB
Player B, please make your move
7
*** Exception: Not an allowed move
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I replace `initial` with the board in your first example, I can do "7" just fine:

```
-- in MancalaBoard.hs
initial = MancalaBoardImpl [5,0,2,7,0,1,5,6,1,7,7,5,0,2] PlayerB
-- ghci TwoPlayerMancala.hs; main

...
The game begins now.
Player A: [5,0,2,7,0,1,5]
Player B: [6,1,7,7,5,0,2]
Current turn: PlayerB
7
Player A: [5,0,2,7,0,1,5]
Player B: [0,2,8,8,6,1,3]
Current turn: PlayerB
Player B, please make your move
```

In other words, I cannot duplicate the error?

(This was a comment up until I wanted to paste the exact output. You should do the same, by the way.)

Comment: That's strange. I get that error when I'm playing through TwoPlayerMancala.hs, starting at initial = [4,4,4,4,4,4,0,4,4,4,4,4,4,0]. I edited my post and appended the full input and output that leads to the error.

Comment: @Jeff following your full input with freshly copy/pasted files from the question, I was still able to do "7" and beyond. `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3`, by the way. Pretty much a clean install.

Comment: Assuming there's still weirdness on your end... Did you try cleaning up all the junk files (caches, object files, etc.)? Start with two fresh .hs files? Try something less than `-O3`, if you're compiling? (Mine worked fine with `-O3`)

Restart the command prompt and/or the computer if you're on Windows? (I had one C compiler compile a perfectly fine `for` loop to an infinite one occasionally, restarting cmd.exe fixed it for a while. Was a pain to debug.)

Comment: Weird. Thanks guys. I restarted the computer and also switched from Ubuntu to Windows 7. One/both of those things helped fix the problem.

Comment: @aib AFAIK there is no -O3 in GHC

Answer (score 0):

You're testing a different board on the command line than you are in `TwoPlayerMancala.hs`. On the command line, it is `PlayerB`'s turn, and `7` is an allowed move. In the board you're testing in `TwoPlayerMancala.hs`, it is `PlayerA`'s turn, and allowed moves are `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`.